# How to use vuejs with symfony

Tags: symfony, vue.js, vuejs2

I found this tutorial that works and allows you to interact symfony with vuejs: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/symfony-vuejs-app/

So far so good but I need to know how to implement an example of this type:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/
within symfony, the idea is to be able to implement code within my project but this part has me stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for server side rendering? https://github.com/Limenius/ReactBundle

Comment: It's interesting the link but that Symfony with React not with VueJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Webpack-Encore-Bundle and inside of the webpack.config.js, add

```
.enableVueLoader()
```

The Flex Recipe already creates a app.js for you. You can then put your vuejs code inside of there like this

```
'use strict';
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    methods: {},
    watch: {},
    components: {}
});
```

After running encore you can include your compiled app.js file inside of twig with the very handy twig function

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

A detailed documentation of webpack-encore can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)